# navigation bar height is reduced from 65 to 44 when device is rotated

Tags: ipad, ios7, uinavigationbar

view controller presented using navigtion controller.when i present view navigation bar height is 65.and when i rotate device navigation bar overlaps with status bar and navigation bar height reduces from 64 to 44.

```
CreateTableViewController * create = [[CreateTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateTableViewController" bundle:nil];
createNotif.notifDelegate = self;
UINavigationController *navbar= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:create];
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0)
{
    [navbar.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    [self presentViewController:navbar animated:YES completion:nil];
}    
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]floatValue ] >= 7.0)
{
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

I have tried to set height of navigation bar progrmatically like
   [navbar setframe:cgrectmake(0,0,1024,65)]; 
I also tried to set constraint in xib file and setted  the following properties.I have tried all the ways of setting constraints in xib and programatically.very bad situation.

Comment: when i tried to print using nslog     NSLog(@"Navbar Height %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame));
It always prints Navbar Height {{0, 0}, {1024, 44}}.But navigation bar height is reduced from 65 to 44 for the first time view rotates.But all the times nslog will print height of navigation bar as 44.

Comment: Did you find any solution of this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.transculent = no in appdelegate it will fix all the issues and in xib file selecte top bar is inferred in all the xibs.